# Loop not looping in batch file

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

I have an issue and can't seem to see where I am going wrong.

I have this code, that is meant to loop through a text file, and look at the last word of the line to see if the user at the start of the line should receive elevated access to their assigned laptop.

However the code just runs through once, and then exits.

```
@echo off
cls
echo.
echo The following script will process the entire list of students, giving each 
echo student administration rights to the laptop and set the laptop description 
echo where necessary.
echo.
pause
cls
FOR /F "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%a IN (accesselevations.txt) DO (
set School1=%%a
set LaptopID=%%b
set Model1=%%c
set Serial1=%%d
set User1=%%e
set Access1=%%f
If /i "%%f" EQU "Admin" goto Elevate2
If /i "%%f" EQU "NoAdmin" goto NoElevate2

:Elevate2
set Desc1=!School1! - !LaptopID! - !Model1! - !Serial1! - !User1!
echo.
echo Now creating local admin account for !user! on !LaptopID!
echo.
echo Description: !Desc1!
echo.
pause
psexec \\!LaptopID! -u GBN\!ocusr! -p !ocpw! -n 10 -e net localgroup Administrators "GBN\!User1!" /add
psexec \\!LaptopID! -u GBN\!ocusr! -p !ocpw! -n 10 -e net config server /srvcomment:"!Desc1!"

:NoElevate2
cls
Echo.
Echo User !user1! is not allowed Local Administrator rights on !LaptopID!.
pause
)
pause
:End
```

The file AccessElevations has confidential data in it so I am not able to post it unfortunately, however it contains something like this

```
School,WorkstationID,LaptopModel,LaptopSerial,StudentUsername,AdminOrNot
School,WorkstationID,LaptopModel,LaptopSerial,StudentUsername,AdminOrNot
School,WorkstationID,LaptopModel,LaptopSerial,StudentUsername,AdminOrNot
School,WorkstationID,LaptopModel,LaptopSerial,StudentUsername,AdminOrNot
```

...and so-on.

I hope I have given enough information, I'm fairly new here.

Thanks in advance for any light you can spread on the issue.

Toby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` or you won't able to use exclamation point on variables.
- Close your `FOR` loop before `Elevate2`
- Change this:

  `If /i "%%f" EQU "Admin" goto Elevate2`

  `If /i "%%f" EQU "NoAdmin" goto NoElevate2`

To:

```
If /i "%%f" EQU "Admin" (CALL:Elevate2) else (CALL:NoElevate2)
```

Using `CALL` command, your script will return to the end of `FOR` loop after elevation operation is done, `GOTO` command connot do this.

- Put `exit/b` before `:NoElevate2`, otherwise your script won'r return to `CALL` command point.

Your code should be like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls
echo.
echo The following script will process the entire list of students, giving each 
echo student administration rights to the laptop and set the laptop description 
echo where necessary.
echo.
pause
cls
FOR /F "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%a IN (accesselevations.txt) DO (
set School1=%%a
set LaptopID=%%b
set Model1=%%c
set Serial1=%%d
set User1=%%e
set Access1=%%f
If /i "%%f" EQU "Admin" (CALL:Elevate2) else (CALL:NoElevate2))
:Elevate2
set Desc1=!School1! - !LaptopID! - !Model1! - !Serial1! - !User1!
echo.
echo Now creating local admin account for !user! on !LaptopID!
echo.
echo Description: !Desc1!
echo.
pause
psexec \\!LaptopID! -u GBN\!ocusr! -p !ocpw! -n 10 -e net localgroup Administrators "GBN\!User1!" /add
psexec \\!LaptopID! -u GBN\!ocusr! -p !ocpw! -n 10 -e net config server /srvcomment:"!Desc1!"
exit/b
:NoElevate2
cls
Echo.
Echo User !user1! is not allowed Local Administrator rights on !LaptopID!.
pause
exit/b

:End
```

Comment: Hey @Rafael I won't be able to test this until I get to work tomorrow now, but looking through it, it all makes sense now, I think you may very well be a legend! I will keep you informed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal
cls
echo.
echo The following script will process the entire list of students, giving each 
echo student administration rights to the laptop and set the laptop description 
echo where necessary.
echo.
pause
cls
FOR /F "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%a IN (accesselevations.txt) DO (
set School1=%%a
set LaptopID=%%b
set Model1=%%c
set Serial1=%%d
set User1=%%e
set Access1=%%f
If /i "%%f" EQU "Admin" CALL :Elevate2
If /i "%%f" EQU "NoAdmin" CALL :NoElevate2
)
GOTO :EOF

:Elevate2
set Desc1=%School1% - %LaptopID% - %Model1% - %Serial1% - %User1%
echo.
echo Now creating local admin account for %user1% on %LaptopID%
echo.
echo Description: %Desc1%
echo.
ECHO psexec \\%LaptopID% -u GBN\%ocusr% -p %ocpw% -n 10 -e net localgroup Administrators "GBN\%User1%" /add
ECHO psexec \\%LaptopID% -u GBN\%ocusr% -p %ocpw% -n 10 -e net config server /srvcomment:"%Desc1%"
GOTO :eof

:NoElevate2
Echo.
Echo User %user1% is not allowed Local Administrator rights on %LaptopID%.
GOTO :EOF
```

Notes:

- `setlocal` added to ensure environment does not get polluted by a run
- Doesn't appear to be much point in setting `Access1` since it isn't used.
- `CALL :routine` rather than `goto` - Not a ood idea to `goto` within a block as some `cmd` versions appear to work differently. Colon is **required** for running internal subroutine
- Within internal subroutines, can use `%var%` since these run in their own context.
- `!var!` syntax is only effective when invoked by `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` (not executed in original batch.)
- `psexec` commands simply `ECHO`ed. Need to remove the preceding `echo` to execute the `psexec`
- Shouldn't a 'remove privileges' routine be applied for 'Nodamin' ?
- `!user!` changed to `%user1%` in `:elevate2` since `user1` is established by the loop, not `user`.

Suitable datafile used for testing was:

```
School1,Workstation1ID,Laptop1Model,Laptop1Serial,Student1Username,Admin
School2,Workstation2ID,Laptop2Model,Laptop2Serial,Student2Username,NoAdmin
School3,Workstation3ID,Laptop3Model,Laptop3Serial,Student3Username,Admin
School4,Workstation4ID,Laptop4Model,Laptop4Serial,Student4Username,NoAdmin
```

not that hard to construct - could easily be done with a prettier version by substituting for names and other sensitive information.